# Springdocs-openapi-ui failed to load API definition

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have previously upgraded

- spring boot from 2.6.x to 2.7.12
- Springdoc-openapi-ui 1.6.5 to 1.7.0
- Classgraph 4.8.139
- Spring framework 5.3.27

Currently on Java 8

And a previous working condition of swagger api is now broken giving below error message. From the log I don’t see any error. So I’m clueless what has happened.
[image: what I see on my landing page now]

Below is a snippet of the code

```
@RestController(“/customer/“)
public class customerController{

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepo;

    @GetMapping(“/allCustomers”)
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers(){
         return customerRepo.findAll().toList();
    }

}
```

I have tried other versions of springdoc-openapi-ui: 1.6.15, 1.6.5, 1.6.8, 1.6.9

Comment: 500 means internal server error. Request is coming to server, but your service is throwing some error. Can you paste error trace

Comment: Do you also have direct dependencies to swagger jars for an older version? Those might interfere with the versions that springdoc-openapi v1.7.0 is using. But, as @G10 is saying: with an error 500 you should expect something in the log. Maybe try to set your log level to debug